# Chrome extension resize while typing

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I just finished my Chrome extension and found out, that the popup changes its height while I'm filling the form.
What could cause it?

http://screenr.com/QIt8

Comment: can you post your html markup ?

Comment: Sure, but it's generated - http://pastie.org/4446820

Comment: i tried that markup on one of my extension, but did not have any similar problem! (chrome 20.0.1132.57 m).  what's you chrome version?